# Coffeescript best way to var

Tags: coffeescript

I was poking around trying to figure a good way to do `var`, and here's one.. is this intentionally in `cs`, because it's not documented?

```
me=;

fetchUser()

  .then((_me) =>
    me = _me
    fetchFriend()
  )
  .then((_you) =>
    me.friend(_you)
  )
  .then(done)
  .otherwise(=>
    console.log ':('
  )
```

compiles correctly to

```
var me;

me = fetchUser().then((function(_this) {
  return function(_me) {
    me = _me;
    return fetchFriend();
  };
})(this)).then((function(_this) {
  return function(_you) {
    return me.friend(_you);
  };
})(this)).then(done).otherwise((function(_this) {
  return function() {
    return console.log(':(');
  };
})(this));
```

#### Edit: it's not compiling correctly.

I wouldn't expect `me = fetchUser()` either, but I didn't see that before 
https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/3098

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a quirk of the parser. The normal way variables are declared in order to establish scoping is just by defining them with some default value (e.g. null).

Comment: Note the unexpected (at least to me) `me = fetchUser()...` in the generated JavaScript. Then note that `me=;6` becomes `var me; me = 6;`. I'd probably call this a parser bug that it is incorrectly (?) ignoring that semicolon.

Comment: oh yea i didn't notice me = fetchUser().. that's weird since there is a semicolon